# Extension of weak derivatives in Bochner spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, bochner-spaces

I am struggling to understand estimate $(15)$ from the following proof from the PDE book by Evans:
[image]

He argues that estimate $(15)$ follows from difference quotients, but I can't understand this. In fact, the theory developed in the earlier section of difference quotients is for real-valued functions, not for functions with values in Banach spaces. What theorem did he use in fact? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The method of difference quotients is also true for functions with values in $L^2$. It can be found for instance in:

> J.L. Lions. Equations différentielles opérationnelles et problèmes aux limites. Die Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften, Bd. 111 Springer-Verlag, Berlin-Göttingen-Heidelberg, 1961.

Comment: Sorry, I can't download the book. May you please state the result being used? I still have no idea.

Comment: Give me your email I will send to you some references on the method.